# Strobe Media Playback flv stream choppy

Tags: flash, stream, media, rtmp

I'm having an issue with video becoming choppy over time with Strobe Media player.

Have the following for settings used on an rtmp source:

```
var parameters =
            {   src: videoSrc
            ,   urlIncludesFMSApplicationInstance: "true"
            ,   optimizeInitialIndex : true
            ,   optimizeBuffering : true
            ,   bufferTime : 30
            ,   initialBufferTime : 30
            ,   expandedBufferTime: 600
            ,   minContinuousPlayback : 20
            ,   streamType: 'recorded'  
            ,   autoPlay: true
            ,   volume : 0
            ,   controlBarAutoHide: true
            ,   backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8'
            ,   javascriptCallbackFunction: "onJavaScriptBridgeCreated"
            };
```

The bitrate of my flv is 400... I've also tested with as low as 200, but regardless of bitrate, the video becomes choppy over time. It seems to progress as it gets farther into the duration. I have also placed used a version where control bar is visible and once I skip into the playback time, it seems to be in sync once again.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar problem while doing tests with strobe media player in Chrome, and the [following post was useful](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/9o9R2hRmx6s) to me:

> Open up Google Chrome and in the address bar type - chrome://plugins/
>   You will then see a Details link over to the right-hand side of the
>   page.  Click the + and youll see a long list of the installed plugins
>   in detail. Look in the Flash section and find the line which has the
>   text - \pepflashplayer.dll Click the Disable link next to this line
>   and restart the browser. Your videos should now run smoothly again

Comment: you are right, this works but its sad that the user has to do this manually